# "test case" - what "case" actually stands for?

Tags: unit-testing

The term **test case** used a lot, but what does it actually mean?

**Test case as Fixture:**

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_case

   A test case in software engineering is a set of conditions or variables under which a tester will determine whether an application or software system is working correctly or not.
2. http://www.junit.org/junit/javadoc/3.8.1/junit/framework/TestCase.html

   A test case defines the fixture to run multiple tests.
3. NUnit:

   [TestFixture]
     public class MyTests
     {
     }

**Test case as tests container/organizer:**

1. http://xunitpatterns.com/test%20case.html

   Usually a synonym for test. In XUnit, it may also refer to a Testcase Class which is actually a Test Suite Factory as well as a place to put a set of related Test Methods.
2. http://xunitpatterns.com/Testcase%20Class%20per%20Feature.html

   - Testcase Class Per Method
   - Testcase Class Per Feature
   - Testcase Class Per User Story
3. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

   They differentiate fixture from TestCase

**Non technical:**

1. http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=test+case

   test case, test suit (a representative legal action whose outcome is likely to become a precedent)

**So, what "case" actually stands for?**

Comment: Case, noun: an often small or portable container for enclosing something, as for carrying or safekeeping; receptacle. (In other words: it means any of those things, depending on the context. Is there anything specific that's bothering you about test cases?)

Comment: I need a hair split.  Is a "case" appropriate for splitting hairs?  And if so, does it actually matter?

Comment: It might work. You should give it a try... just in case.

Comment: @oirac, I think my initial understanding of "test case" as a container (and your definition as well) was wrong. Yes, TestCase class is physically a container for methods. But semantically it is an example/situation to test the system in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"case" means "an example of something".

For example:

```
if( x < 3 ){ }
```

A *case* when this may go into the block, is when `x = 2`. Another *case* could be when it won't go in, i.e. `x = 9`.

Comment: Interesting... Can I call a test method Should_throw_exception_if_password_to_short the test case? As this method describes particular "example". Than in context of jUnit the TestCase should be seen as TestCases.

Comment: xUnit Test Patterns seems to give such meaning as you suggested: "the test fixture will be newly constructed for each test case in the Testcase Class."

Comment: Also, in question itself I wrongly classified this definition "Usually a synonym for test" - it confirms your defintion as well.

Answer (score 4):

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/case

1. an instance of the occurrence, existence, etc., of something: Sailing in such a storm was a case of poor judgment.

Comment: It is hard for me to think about "test case" as "test occurrence" or "test existance".

Comment: it is an instance of a test. 1 test case.

Answer (score 1):

case = situation or condition